# Accessing (/importing) Scala Enumerations

Tags: scala, enumeration

For the following HwLogger.PersisterType  enumeration:

```
object HwLogger extends Serializable {

  object PersisterType extends Enumeration {
    type Persisters = Value
    val FilePersister, HdfsPersister, SocketPersister = Value
  }

}
```

In the companion class - how do we access it? Notice the slew of imports below ..

```
class HwLogger extends Serializable {
  import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  import HwLogger.PersisterType._
  import HwLogger.PersisterType
  var persisterTypes = ArrayBuffer[PersisterType]()   // Compiler says " error: not found: type PersisterType"
  def setDefaults : Unit = {
    import PersisterType._
    persisterTypes ++ FilePersister ++ HdfsPersister 
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**  After the accepted answer (and syntax correction on the arraybuffer append operators) here is the corrected code:

```
object HwLogger extends Serializable {

  object PersisterType extends Enumeration {
    type Persisters = Value
    val FilePersister, HdfsPersister, SocketPersister = Value
  }

}

class HwLogger extends Serializable {
  import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  import HwLogger.PersisterType._
  import HwLogger.PersisterType
  var persisterTypes = ArrayBuffer[Persisters]()    // This is the fix (Persisters instead of PersisterType)
  def setDefaults : Unit = {
    import PersisterType._
    persisterTypes :+ FilePersister :+ HdfsPersister
  }

}
```

** Another update **

Changing the enumeration object will avoid the hassles:

```
object HwLogger extends Serializable {

  object PersisterType extends Enumeration {
    type PersisterType = Value    // Changed the "type" to be same as object name
    val FilePersister, HdfsPersister, SocketPersister = Value
  }

}

class HwLogger extends Serializable {
  import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  import HwLogger.PersisterType._
  import HwLogger.PersisterType
  var persisterTypes = ArrayBuffer[PersisterType]()    // Revert back to PersisterType
  def setDefaults : Unit = {
    import PersisterType._
    persisterTypes :+ FilePersister :+ HdfsPersister
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of elements in the Enumeration is `Persisters`, not `PersisterType`. `PersisterType` is only a value. You do need to import the types and values inside of `PersisterType` to use the `Enumeration`.

```
class HwLogger extends Serializable {
  import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  import HwLogger.PersisterType._
  val persisterTypes = ArrayBuffer[Persisters]()
  def setDefaults: Unit = {
    persisterTypes += FilePersister += HdfsPersister 
  }
}
```

Comment: wingedsubmariner?  how are the wings exercised underwater?

Comment: I looked at your code and your comment. Pls note in the OP the following import was already included:  import HwLogger.PersisterType._   So what is the new logic you are suggesting?

Comment: `ArrayBuffer[Persisters]` is the key change you need. As for the name, I just like the imagery it evokes :)

Comment: Oh i saw it just a moment before your last post.  thx for the good eyes.  If i had wings i'd stick to the sky, avoid the water drag.

Comment: In the end the best fix was to change the "type" to be same as the object name.  I had not intended for them to diverge, but so it happened.